# Htaccess rewrite not liking dashes

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use the following rewrite rule to behind the scenes rewrite addresses such as /pageName and /pageName/ to index.php?page=pageName. It works perfectly except when the pageName contains a -.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

How can I get these rewrite rules to accept any input (or at least input containing A-Z, 1-9, and -'s.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (probably...) do not want to rewrite any existing files, so you could use something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Note that I made the trailing slash optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` is the equivalent of `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`. e.g. upper+lower case alphabetical characters, and the undercore. `-` is **NOT** part of it, so you'll have to explicitly allow it:

```
^([\w\-])$
```

by creating your own character class.